# My variable keeps changing its value to 3435973836

Tags: c

Whenever I run my code the variable bookcost changes itself to the value: 3435973836 .

It does this after it reaches the processingData function. I do not  know why it keeps doing this! I have already written this program without functions and it worked fine :( This is my second programming class, it is online and there is almost no support from the professor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputData(int* inputs,int* booknmbr, int* nmbrpurchased, int* bookcost);
void processingData(int bookcost, int nmbrpurchased, int totalpurch, int costaccu);
void outputInfo(int booknmbr, int nmbrpurchased, int bookcost, int* total);

    int bookcounter = 0;
    int totalpurch = 0;
    int costaccu = 0;
    int totalcostaccu = 0;


int main ()

{
    int booknmbr;
    int nmbrpurchased;
    int bookcost; 
    int bookcounter = 0;
    int cycleRun;
    int total;
    int inputs;

    printf("Run Program? 1 for Yes or -1 for No \n"); // ask user to input product name
    scanf("%d", &cycleRun);
    while (cycleRun != -1) 
    {

        inputData(&inputs, &booknmbr, &nmbrpurchased, &bookcost);
        processingData(bookcost, nmbrpurchased, totalpurch, costaccu);
        outputInfo(booknmbr, nmbrpurchased, bookcost, &total);

        printf("Run Program? 1 for Yes or -1 for No \n"); // ask user to input product name
        scanf("%d", &cycleRun);
    }
}

void inputData(int* inputs, int* booknmbr, int* nmbrpurchased, int* bookcost)
{
    printf( "\nEnter the Book Product Number?\n" );
    scanf("%d", &booknmbr);

    printf( "Enter the Number of Books Purchased?\n" );
    scanf("%d", &nmbrpurchased);

    printf( "Enter the Cost of the Book Purchased?\n");
    scanf("%d", &bookcost);

    printf( "TEST: %u\n", bookcost);

    return;
}

void processingData(int bookcost, int nmbrpurchased, int totalpurch, int costaccu)
{
    int total;

    printf( "TEST: %u\n", bookcost);

    total = bookcost * nmbrpurchased;
    totalpurch = totalpurch + nmbrpurchased;
    costaccu = costaccu + bookcost;
    totalcostaccu = totalcostaccu + (bookcost * nmbrpurchased);

    printf( "TEST: %u\n", bookcost);

    return;
}

void outputInfo(int booknmbr, int nmbrpurchased, int bookcost, int* total)
{
    printf( "\nBook Product number entered is: %u\n", booknmbr);
    printf( "Quantity of Book Purchased is: %u\n", nmbrpurchased);
    printf( "Cost of the Book Purchased is: %u\n", bookcost);
    printf( "Total cost of books is: $%u\n", total);

    return;
}

void outputSummary(int bookcounter, int totalpurch, int costaccu, int totalcostaccu)
{
    printf( "\n\nNumber of records processed = %u\n", bookcounter);
    printf( "Number of books purchased = %u\n", totalpurch);
    printf( "Cost of the books purchased = $%u\n", costaccu);
    printf( "Total cost for all book purchases = $%u\n", totalcostaccu);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the *addresses* of your variables to `inputData` ... try this:

```
/* not using inputs? */
void inputData(int* pinputs, int* pbooknmbr, int* pnmbrpurchased, int* pbookcost)  {
    printf( "\nEnter the Book Product Number?\n" );
    scanf("%d", pbooknmbr);
    printf( "Enter the Number of Books Purchased?\n" );
    scanf("%d", pnmbrpurchased);
    printf( "Enter the Cost of the Book Purchased?\n");
    scanf("%d", pbookcost);
    printf( "TEST: %u\n", *pbookcost);
}
```

You have a similar problem with `total` in `outputInfo`. You need to read carefully though your code and attend to details, paying attention to which variables are pointers and which are scalar values. It helps to name pointers differently, as I did here.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I actually don't even know what the difference between pointers and scalar values are so I guess I need to do some studying.

Comment: At SO, we show our appreciation by accepting helpful answers. A variable declared `int*` is a pointer; it holds the address of an `int` variable.  An `int` variable holds an `int` (an integer with an implementation-defined number of bits) ... what I'm calling  ascalar value here. Addresses are scalar values too ... perhaps I should have just said "non-pointer". Do study and learn about pointers before you use them, else you will suffer greatly.

Answer (score 7):

A quick search shows 3435973836 to be the value Windows gives unassigned memory on x64 - this is telling, as it suggests you have pointers pointing out into nowhere.

Let's see what's going on here.  In `main()`, you define a bunch of ints.  You pass references to those ints when you say `inputData(&inputs, &booknmbr, &nmbrpurchased, &bookcost)`.  That function has a signature of `void inputData(int* inputs, int* booknmbr, int* nmbrpurchased, int* bookcost)` - so far so good.

...then you `scanf("%d", &booknmbr)`.  Think about this for a second.

That's right.  You're passing `scanf()` a reference to a pointer to the integer you want to fill, rather than just the pointer.  It's an easy trap to fall into since you've probably always written calls to `scanf()` that way & it's become habit.  Replacing that with a `scanf("%d", booknmbr)` makes the world right again.